# Closing new nonchild window in Qt

Tags: qt, qwidget

i'm trying to make 2 windows. 2nd should be called in 1st. I don't connect them child->parent.
But when i called 2nd window and closed it 1st window closed too. What should i do?
Both windows are inhereted from QWidget.
C++ and Qt

---

Sorry for my poor describe.
I have a main window. Class inherited from QMainWindow. That i created 2nd window. Class inherited from QWidget.
In first (main window) i'm creating and calling 2nd window

```
ConfigWindow *ConfWindow = new ConfigWindow();
ConfWindow->show();
```

Without giving link to parent. Everything works fine, but when i close 2nd window (config-window) my main window is closing too. I needn't in this. What should i do to block closing main window after config-window closing.

### Hope describe a little better.

My first window has this flags:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Without them everything is fine. Could i change something if i need that flags in my window?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't suggest anything with just this information.  Can you edit the question to post more information?  Ideally, a brief code example showing what you're doing with the two windows, as well as your main() function.

Comment: Second the above the comment. The question is written poorly, e.g. what on earth exactly you are doing when you say "I called 2nd window"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need something like:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

Here is the test program: http://pastebin.com/f5903c5f4.

Beware, now you need to **explicitly** call [quit()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) in the destructor of your main window.

If you read [QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop), you will find out that:

> If this property is true, the applications quits when the last visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) with the Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is closed. By default this attribute is set for all widgets except for sub-windows

Because your main window is a (frameless) tool window, it does count. That leaves ConfWindow as the only non sub-windows top-level widget. Thus, if you close ConfWindow, it provokes the application instance to quit.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code, then there is a huge bug in Qt.
The code above should never close your first Windows, there must be something else wrong.
Is the application closed or does it crash?

**Remark**
 
Who is deleting configWindow?  There is a `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute that deletes the window after it is closed.

```
ConfigWindow *confWindow = new configWindow();
configWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
confWindow->show();
```

Comment: Is the application closed or does it crash?

Comment: There is something else wrong, we need more information (code).